# Find open UDID and mac address in phone

Tags: java, mac-address, udid

Can I find UDID and MAC address programmatically using pure java code.

If no, please suggest me any self owned method which you used to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Since JDK 1.6 developers are able to **access network card detail** via the class `NetworkInterface`.

To fetch **the mac address of the system** , there are a couple of good tutorials available here:

- [How to get mac address using Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/)

These tutorials show the legacy way as well as the modern way to access the network card.

Now, for the `UDID` part, I am **assuming it is an Android Device** there are a **couple of choices as to what can be used as a unique identifier for a device**. The choices generally narrow down to:

- `MAC address`
- `Serial Number`
- `ANDROID_ID`

Of this it is **better to use ANDROID_ID as the UDID** because:

1. Though it may be possible to retrieve a Mac address from a device’s WiFi or Bluetooth hardware , it is not recommended because not all devices have WiFi. Also, if the WiFi is not turned on, the hardware may not report the Mac address.
2. Since Android 2.3 (“Gingerbread”) this is available via [android.os.Build.SERIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SERIAL). Devices without telephony are required to report a unique device ID here; some phones may do so also.

More specifically, the `ANDROID_ID` is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It is reset when the device is wiped.ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier but there are downsides:

1. It is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”).
2. There has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

**References:**

- [What Is a Network Interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html)
- [NetworkInterface](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html)
- [Identifying Installations](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)